# Compare two pictures with matlab

Tags: matlab

I used [`imshowpair`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html) to compare two grey-scaled pictures. I used the `'green-magenta'` ColorChannel to display the differences.
I have two problems:

1. Some of the differences between the two pictures are pretty small. How can I scale the ColorChannel that it shows the small differences more colorful?
2. Can I hide the original image to see the color better?

Answer (score 1):

When I am working with transformations on grayscale images, I need to compare the result with the original.  I find making a figure with four subplots comprised of the original image, the final image, the difference (subtraction) and a cdf of the difference vector can be reasonably useful.

If most of the difference image is zero, you can substitute "NaN" for it in that surface plot.  This will show only nonzero values.

Percent difference can also be useful.  This will often take small changes and scale them for visibility.

So you can have your overlay image, then a difference image as subplots of the same figure.

Example code:

```
I = fitsread('solarspectra.fts');
I = mat2gray(I);
I2 = imrotate(I,-1,'bilinear','crop');

d=(I(:)-I2(:));

figure(1); clf
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(I)
colorbar
title('Original')

subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(I2)
colorbar
title('New')

subplot(2,2,3)
imshow(I-I2)
colorbar
title('Difference')

subplot(2,2,4)
cdfplot(d)
title('eCDF(diff)')
```

You might also use find to find the subset of changes, and impose a false z-value increase to improve visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logarithmic scale in `imagesc` plots.

```
% Plot the data
I = double(imread('image.tif'));
imagesc(log(I))
colormap gray
```

Look this link: http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237161

Comment: If I use *log* the intensity of the color doesn't improve.

Comment: If I use *log* I am not able anymore to overlap the pictures perfectly. Can I save the parameter of the imregister function to overlap it later the same way?
<br><br>
I used the following code:

<br><br>
p_00 = log(double(imrotate(dicomread('dci_00.dcm'),-90)));<br>
p_90 = log(double(dicomread('dci_90.dcm')));<br>
figure, imshowpair(p_90, p_00)<br>
[optimizer,metric] = imregconfig('multimodal');<br>
optimizer.MaximumIterations = 1000;<br>

movingRegistered = imregister(p_90, p_00, 'affine', optimizer, metric);<br>
figure, imshowpair(movingRegistered, p_00)<br>

Comment: This is not going to help OP with his `imshowpair`question.